# JavaFx: TableView - unbind all properties

Tags: java, javafx

I have a `TableView` and the columns for it I create like this:

```
TableColumn<Foo,String> fieldColumn=new TableColumn("field");
fieldColumn.setCellValueFactory(data->data.getValue().getFieldProperty());
tableView.add(fieldColumn);
```

Now I want to destroy my `tableView` but I want to continue to use all `foos`. That's why I want to unbind `foos`' properties from table/column. How to do it?

Answer (score 1):

If you remove the `TableColumn`s, the listeners will be removed during the next layout pass. This allows you to remove the listeners added by the `TableView` by clearing the columns and calling `layout()`:

`Item` class for allowing to get the number of listeners to the property

```
public class Item {

    private final Set<Object> listeners = new HashSet<>();

    public Item(String value) {
        this.value.set(value);
    }

    private final StringProperty value = new SimpleStringProperty() {

        @Override
        public void removeListener(ChangeListener<? super String> listener) {
            super.removeListener(listener);
            listeners.remove(listener);
        }

        @Override
        public void addListener(ChangeListener<? super String> listener) {
            super.addListener(listener);
            listeners.add(listener);
        }

        @Override
        public void removeListener(InvalidationListener listener) {
            super.removeListener(listener);
            listeners.remove(listener);
        }

        @Override
        public void addListener(InvalidationListener listener) {
            super.addListener(listener);
            listeners.add(listener);
        }

    };

    public final StringProperty valueProperty() {
        return this.value;
    }

    public int getListenerCount() {
        return listeners.size();
    }

}
```

Text `Application`

```
private void printListenerCount(String message) {
    System.out.println(message + tableView.getItems().stream().mapToInt(Item::getListenerCount).sum());
}

private TableView<Item> tableView;

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    tableView = new TableView<>();
    tableView.getItems().addAll(new Item("a"), new Item("b"), new Item("c"));

    TableColumn<Item, String> column = new TableColumn<>();
    column.setCellValueFactory(cd -> cd.getValue().valueProperty());

    tableView.getColumns().add(column);

    Button btn = new Button("print listener count");
    btn.setOnAction((ActionEvent event) -> {
        printListenerCount("listeners: ");
    });

    Button btn2 = new Button("clear columns");
    btn2.setOnAction(evt -> {
        tableView.getColumns().clear();

        // do layout to remove the listeners added for the columns
        tableView.layout();

        printListenerCount("after clear columns: ");
    });

    Scene scene = new Scene(new VBox(tableView, btn, btn2));

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

Pressing the `print listener count` and then the `clear columns` buttons will result in the following output:

```
listeners: 3
after clear columns: 0
```